# Error trying to use variable for the field name in an Excel Power Query SelectRows line

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have the following Excel 2016 Power Query (Get & Transform query). It works fine, but I'm trying to use variables for the field names in the two SelectRows lines:

```
let

    //Variables:
        //Server Name:
            DefnameServerName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_SERVER_NAME"]}[Content],
            ServerName = DefnameServerName{0}[Column1],
        //Database Name:
            DefnameDatabaseName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_DATABASE_NAME"]}[Content],
            DatabaseName = DefnameDatabaseName{0}[Column1],
        //Schema Name:
            DefnameSchemaName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_SCHEMA_NAME"]}[Content],
            SchemaName = DefnameSchemaName{0}[Column1],
        //Table Name:
            DefnameTableName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_TABLE_NAME"]}[Content],
            TableName = DefnameTableName{0}[Column1],
        //ID Field Name:
            DefnameFieldNameID = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_FIELDNAME_ID"]}[Content],
            FieldNameID = DefnameFieldNameID{0}[Column1],
        //Customer Field Name:
            DefnameFieldNameCustomer = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_FIELDNAME_CUSTOMER"]}[Content],
            FieldNameCustomer = DefnameFieldNameCustomer{0}[Column1],
        //Region Field Name:
            DefnameFieldNameRegion = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_FIELDNAME_REGION"]}[Content],
            FieldNameRegion = DefnameFieldNameRegion{0}[Column1],
        //Month Field Name:
            DefnameFieldNameMonth = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_FIELDNAME_MONTH"]}[Content],
            FieldNameMonth = DefnameFieldNameMonth{0}[Column1],
        //Forecast Value Field Name:
            DefnameFieldNameForecastValue = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_FIELDNAME_FORECAST_VALUE"]}[Content],
            FieldNameForecastValue = DefnameFieldNameForecastValue{0}[Column1],

    //Parameters:
        //ID:
            DefnameParameterID = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_PARAMETER_ID"]}[Content],
            ParameterID = DefnameParameterID{0}[Column1],
        //Customer:
            DefnameParameterCustomer = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IMPORT_PARAMETER_CUSTOMER"]}[Content],
            ParameterCustomer = DefnameParameterCustomer{0}[Column1],

    Source = Sql.Database(ServerName, DatabaseName),
    dbo_MidtermOmnibusForecast = Source{[Schema=SchemaName,Item=TableName]}[Data],
    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(dbo_MidtermOmnibusForecast,{FieldNameID, FieldNameCustomer, FieldNameMonth, FieldNameForecastValue, FieldNameRegion}),
    FilterByUUID = Table.SelectRows(RemoveOtherColumns, each ([UUID] = ParameterID)),
    FilterByCustomer = Table.SelectRows(FilterByUUID, each ([ForecastName] = ParameterCustomer)),
    PivotMonths = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(FilterByCustomer, {{FieldNameMonth, type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(FilterByCustomer, {{FieldNameMonth, type text}}, "en-US")[ForecastDate]), FieldNameMonth, FieldNameForecastValue, List.Sum),
    SortByCustomerThenRegion = Table.Sort(PivotMonths,{{FieldNameCustomer, Order.Ascending}, {FieldNameRegion, Order.Ascending}})
in
    SortByCustomerThenRegion
```

I've tried this:

```
    FilterByUUID = Table.SelectRows(RemoveOtherColumns, each ([FieldNameID] = ParameterID)),
    FilterByCustomer = Table.SelectRows(FilterByUUID, each ([FieldNameCustomer] = ParameterCustomer)),
```

And I've tried this:

```
    FilterByUUID = Table.SelectRows(RemoveOtherColumns, each (FieldNameID = ParameterID)),
    FilterByCustomer = Table.SelectRows(FilterByUUID, each (FieldNameCustomer = ParameterCustomer)),
```

But they both break the query. What do I need to do to use the variables for the field names in the two SelectRows lines?

Answer (score 2):

An answer was provided at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13df0744-4f27-4f3a-8565-7e24b1d73c17/error-trying-to-use-variable-for-the-field-name-in-a-selectrows-line?forum=powerquery:

You cannot use square brackets with variable field names, but have to use Record.Field instead like this:

```
FilterByUUID = Table.SelectRows(RemoveOtherColumns, each (Record.Field(_, FieldNameID) = ParameterID)),
```

(This is only necessary where square brackets are used around the field name, as they are in this SelectRows line. Where there are no square brackets, as in my SelectColumns line in my code above, you can just swap in the variable name as I did.  --Greg)

Comment: 2023, this works